# Determine the derivative in an interval.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine the first derivative of $f(x)=\ln(\sin^2(x^2))$ in an interval:  $(0, \infty)$

I determined the derivative just in the usual way, but then I saw I have to do this for this open interval. Honestly, I have no idea how should I proceed. Is this interval value relative for the assignment anyway?

Comment: The reason for the interval is because $\ln(x)$ is only defined on the interval $(0,\infty)$

Comment: The results involve $\tan(x)$ and I guess only the values where $x>0$ are of importance here.

Comment: @JEET TRIVEDI Yes, but $sin^2(x^2)$ cannot be negative.

Comment: @CommonerG That is true. The question probably mentions the interval in case the reader isn't able to infer this

Comment: I disagree. $f(x)$ is defined for all $x$ (except $\sqrt{n\,\pi}$). There is no real reason for the restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative is $(4x) cot(x^2)$.

Since $sin^2(x^2)\geq0$, $f(x)$ is defined for negative $x$ as well and the derivative is no different.